# How can I select 4 distinct values from 2 tables containing many rows of data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables that Im trying to select 4 results from ordered by GalleryID DESC. The fields Im looking to return are GalleryID, GalleryTitle, GalleryDate from the Galleries table, and MediaThumb from the Media Table.

Now the catch is that the Media table has multiples of 10 of GalleryID's.  So, there could be 10 rows in the Media table with the same GalleryID. All I need is one MediaThumb to go along with the galleryid.

Im not sure how to formulate a query to return 4 distinct galleryid's from the galleries table and a MediaThumb from the media table.

Essentially what im trying to do is return 4 unique photo galleries with a cover photo from the media table.

Any help would be appreciated. I provided a snapshot via query designer in sqlserver of my 2 tables.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Instead of showing a diagram of the relationship, can you show some *abbreviated* sample data and desired results (e.g. some rows you want to keep, and some rows you want to discard, and constrain it to pertinent columns only please)?

Comment: You say you want 4 distinct Galleries records, and a single Media record to go along with it right?  Does it matter which 4 Galleries records, and which of the corresponding Media records for each that you choose?  Do you just want the first 4 Galleries records fetched, and the first corresponding Media record fethced for each?

Comment: There's a linq tag listed. Is this is TSQL or Linq-to-Sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 4 
    g.GalleryID
    ,g.GalleryTitle
    ,g.GalleryDate
    ,MAX(m.MediaThumb) AS MaxMediaThumb
FROM Galleries g
    INNER JOIN Media m
        ON g.GalleryID = m.GalleryID
GROUP BY g.GalleryID, g.GalleryTitle, g.GalleryDate
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was getting at in my comment on the OP.  From his wording it seems this is what he wants, but it needs better explanation.

Comment: @Jim - I hear you.  This answer is based on the information we received from the OP.  If more info is provided, we may see a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand

```
SELECT DISTINCT(g.GalleryID), g.GalleryTitle, g.GalleryDate, MAX(m.MediaThumb)
FROM Galleries g
    INNER JOIN Media m
        ON g.GalleryID = m.GalleryID
GROUP BY g.GalleryID, g.GalleryTitle, g.GalleryDate
```

Comment: DISTINCT with MAX and GROUP BY? Are you sure this works the way you think it does? What does DISTINCT add? Also what does this do to limit the results to 4 rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for each GalleryID you want any one MediaThumb and you don't care which. If that is correct, then I suggest you SELECT max(MediaThumb) and GROUP BY GalleryID.