# I need to convert this SQL Query to LINQ so that I can use it inside my project

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by

Someone from stackoverflow recently helped me form this sql query to return the data i was looking for.

I need to convert this into a LINQ statement so that I can use it inside my ASP.NET MVC3 C# project.

Thanks!

```
SELECT TOP 4 a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, MAX(b.MediaThumb) AS MediaThumb
FROM Galleries a
INNER JOIN Media b
ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
GROUP BY a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate
ORDER BY a.GalleryID desc
```

Comment: check this - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFQuerySamples for different samples and should help you design different queries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you just didn't ask this question instead of asking for the TSQL in your previous question: [how can I select 4 distinct...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440317/how-can-i-select-4-distinct-values-from-2-tables-containing-many-rows-of-data-in/11440380#11440380)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: here's a version that groups as per the T-Sql given:

```
var Results = (from g in DB.Galleries
               join m in DB.Media
               on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID
               group m by new { g.GalleryID, g.GalleryTitle, g.GalleryDate } into grp
               orderby grp.Key.GalleryID descending
               select new LatestGalleries
               {
                   GalleryID = grp.Key.GalleryID,
                   GalleryTitle = grp.Key.GalleryTitle,
                   GalleryDate = grp.Key.GalleryDate,
                   MediaThumb = grp.FirstOrDefault().MediaThumb
               });
```

Comment: You are not grouping, and your ordering occurs after your take, which will not guarantee the right top 4

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
(
  from a in galleries
  join b in media on b.GalleryID equals a.GalleryID
  group by new {a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate} into grouping
  order by grouping.Key.GalleryID
  select new {grouping.Key.GalleryID, grouping.Key.GalleryTitle, grouping.Key.GalleryDate, grouping.Max(x=>x.MediaThumb)}
).Take(4)
```

Comment: Getting an error on group by: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AnonymousType#1>' because it is not a delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure EF [Navigation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx) on Media first, then:

```
var q = (from a in db.Galleries
        group a by new { a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate } into g
        orderby g.Key.GalleryID descending
        select new
        {
            GalleryID = g.Key.GalleryID,
            GalleryTitle = g.Key.GalleryTitle,
            GalleryDate = g.Key.GalleryDate,
            MediaThumb = g.Max(a => a.Media) // Gallery.Media is a navigation property
        }).Take(4);
```